# The thickest neoprene suit for swimming?

Tags: swimming, cold

What is the thickest available neoprene suit appropriate for swimming?

I have a swim suit marked 2/3/4 mm. I don't know which is where, but it was OK as long as the water was about 15 grad, and below was too cold. I know there are apnea suits, which are also good for swimming, up to 5mm. Everything above is scuba dive, and they are definitely not good for swimming.

Is there anything designed for swimming in cold waters?

Answer (score 2):

5mm wetsuits are fine for swimming in water temperatures down to around 3 or 4 Celsius. For water around freezing, you will want a dry suit if you plan to spend much time immersed.

Be aware that there are no suits suitable for those temperatures that are easy to swim in - the shoulder joints are stiffer than you would want.

Of greatest criticality in cold water for me are my neoprene boots (and my inflatable flamingo ring :-) :

[image]

Comment: What temperatures are fine for you for swimming in trunks only?

Comment: It turns out as of this week, 1.5°C for about 5 minutes. But a wetsuit gives me an extra 10 minutes